# $f:V_1\to V_2$ continuous impies that $f$ pulls back closed sets to closed sets

Tags: real-analysis, functions, proof-verification

Let $f: V_1 \to V_2$ be a continuous function, $V_1$ and $V_2$ be normed vector spaces. Need to prove that $U\subseteq V_2$ is closed implies $f^{-1}(U)$ is closed.

> Proof:

Since $U$ is a closet set, it contains all its limit points. Let $y\in U$, then $\exists \{y_n\}\subseteq U$ such that $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}y_n=y$. Since $f$ is continuous, $\exists x_n\in f^{-1}(U)$ such that $f(x_n)=y_n$, and $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} f(x_n)=f(x)=y\in U$. This implies that $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} x_n = x = f^{-1}(y)\in f^{-1}(U)$. Thus $x$ is a limit point of $f^{-1}(U)$, and $f^{-1}(U)$ is closed, as required.

Please let me know if my proof is OK.

Comment: Note that the statement is false: consider $\mathbb R$ with its standard topology, and $f(x)=x^2$ and $U=(-1,\infty)$. $f^{-1}(U)=\mathbb R$  is closed but $U$ is not. The true statement is "if $U$ is closed, then $f^{-1}(U)$ is closed".

Comment: Your proof is incorrect since it assumes that the inverse function $f^{-1}$ exists. (Or maybe you forgot to say that $f$ is invertible, in which case the statement would be correct).

Comment: @Taladris, I think $(-1,\infty)$ cannot be in the image of $f$ because only non-negative numbers are in the image of $f$.

Comment: @Taladris;it is not necessary to assume that $f^{-1}$ exists;it always exists ;it means $f^{-1}(U)=\{x:f(x)\in U\}$

Comment: I considered $f$ as a function $\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$, so $(-1,\infty)$ is included in the *codomain* $V_2$. Also, $V_2=[0,\infty)$ would not be a vector space...

Comment: @learnmore: I didn't say it was necessary ^^. Just that the OP assumed $f^{-1}$ existed since $x=f^{-1}(y)$ is used in his/her proof.

Comment: I told you that only $f^{-1}(U)$ always exists regardless of OP's assumption@Taladris

Comment: @Taladris, the statement is that the pullback of closed sets is mapped onto closed sets. $(-1, \infty)$ is not a closed set.
Also, it is not necessary to assume that $f$ is bijective because I said in my proof that $\exists x_n \in f^{-1}(U)$ such that $f(x_n) = y_n$. There may exist $x'\neq x_n$ such that $f(x')=y_n$, but there is no problem with it, we are only considering some points for a corresponding sequence.

Comment: @learnmore: I am not sure I understand your comment then. For sure, $f^{-1}(U)$ exists, whatever the function $f$ is, and I never claimed the contrary. But $f^{-1}$, as a function from $V_2$ into $V_1$, and the $f^{-1}(y)$ that appears in the proof,  don't exist in general, unless you assume $f$ is invertible.

Comment: @sequence: "the statement is that the pullback of closed sets is mapped onto closed sets.". Sorry but this is not the same statement as in the question.

Comment: @Taladris, $f^{-1}(y)$ may map to more than one point, that is true. But I do take care of it in my proof by saying that there exists $x_n\in f^{-1}(U)$ such that $f(x_n) = y_n\in U$. What I'm saying is that I'm neglecting the other points not equal to $x_n$, and only associate $y_n$ with some $x_n$, to make a corresponding sequence.

Comment: @Taladris, "this is not the same statement as in the question" I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: " the pullback of closed sets is mapped onto closed sets." would be "for any closed set $U$ of $V_2$, $f(f^{-1}(U))$ is closed" (note that $f^{-1}(f(U))\subset U$, but we don't have equality in general), since the pullback of $U$ is $f^{-1}(U)$.

Comment: @Taladris, the pullback of $U$ under $f$ is defined as $f^{-1}(U)$, not $f(f^{-1}(U))$, which is actually $U$ itself.

Comment: @sequence: I know I know. But your statement is about the image ("is mapped onto") of the pullback. And no, the two sets $U$ and $f(f^{-1}(U))$ are not the same in general. Please refer to my answer below, since comments are not the place for extended discussions, and tend to be deleted.

Answer (score 1):

Since comments are not for extended discussions, and the question asks about proof checking,
I wrote some of the comment I made as an answer.

There are several problems with the proof, and the statement:

1. The statement "U is closed if and only if $f^{-1}(U)$ is closed" is actually false: 
   consider the function $f$ from $\mathbb R$ into $\mathbb R$ defined by $f(x)=x^2$ and $U=(-1,\infty)$. Then $f^{-1}(U)=\mathbb R$ is closed but $U$ isn't.
2. A true statement would be "if $U$ is closed, then $f^{-1}(U)$ is also closed" (the only if  part of the OP's statement). This is actually the title of the question, which is different from the statements in the body and in the comments.
3. Another fix would be to assume that $f$ is an homeomorphism.
4. The statement does not mean that "the pullback of closed sets are mapped onto closed sets" which means "if $U$ is closed, then $f(f^{-1}(U))$ is also 
   closed", since the pullback of $U$ is $f^{-1}(U)$. The statement in the body of the question means "$U$ is closed if and only if its pullback $f^{-1}(U)$ is closed".
   Again, the statement in the title is the correct one.
5. The proof is wrong in several places. First of all, as pointed out by learnmore's answer, a proof should start by considering $y$ in $f^{-1}(U)$.
6. The fact that $y_n$ belongs to $U$ does not imply that there exists $x_n$ in $f^{-1}(U)$ such that $f(x_n)=y_n$. Indeed, consider the same function 
   $f(x)=x^2$ and in the first example, but this time $U=[-1,\infty)$, which is closed. Then, for $y_n=-1\in U$, there is no $x_n$ satisfying $f(x_n)=y_n$. 
   $x_n\in f^{-1}(U)$ only means that $f(x_n)\in U$. But $f(f^{-1}(U))$ is only a subset of $U$ in general, and actually, "for any subset $U$, $f(f^{-1}(U))=U$"
   is equivalent to the surjectivity of $f$.
7. May the sequence $\{x_n\}$ 
   exists, there is no reason it has a limit.
8. The proof assumes incorrectly that the inverse function $f^{-1}$ exists, which is false in general.

Comment: I think I've already clearly answered each of these claims, except for 7. For 7, $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} x_n$ exists, which clearly follows in my proof.

Comment: Unfortunately no. Where did you prove that $\lim_{n\to\infty}$ exist? Do you still disagree with my counter-example (point 1.) to the statement in the body of the question (note that the question in the title is true, so the question can be easily fixed)

Comment: I created a sequence by construction. That is, I showed that there exists $x_n\in f^{-1}(U)$ which corresponds to $y_n$ in $f(U)$. Since $f$ is continuous, $x_n$ converges to $x$ (and I showed it).

For point 1, it is completely irrelevant, because $(-1, \infty)$ is not closed, and because it is not even in the image of $f$.

Comment: For $f(x)=x^2$ and $y_n=1$, I can choose $x_n=(-1)^n$. Does $\{x_n\}$ have a limit?

Comment: For the point $1.$, the image of the function does not appear in the statement. It is focusing on the image that is irrelevant. Isn't $V_1=V_2=\mathbb R$ a normed vector space (for its standard Euclidean structure)? Isn't $f(x)=x^2$ a continuous function from $V_1$ to $V_2$? Isn't $U=(-1,\infty)$ a subset of $V_2$? But $U$ is not closed even if $f^{-1}(U)$ is closed, so the statement **in the body** of the question is wrong. The *if* part doesn't stand to inspection.

Comment: I didn't say "if and only if", that's why the statement is correct. If $f$ pulls back closed sets to closed sets, this doesn't mean that it doesn't pull back some open sets to closed sets. However, it can't possibly pull back $(-1, \infty)$, but it can pull back $(0, \infty)$, since $(-1, 0)$ is not in the image of $f$.

Comment: Read your question again, you did write "if and only if". There is no mention of the image of $f$ in any of your statements, so my counter-example stands. Anyway, the point 1. is the least of the problems in what you wrote...

Comment: Actually yes, I did write that. However, your example does not work since $f$ does not pull back $(-1, 0) \subset (-1, \infty)$ to anything.

Comment: I asked my prof, he said that my proof is correct.

Comment: You are kind of exhausting. Where in the definition of pullback is the image of $f$ involved? Nowhere, at least in most standard definitions of pullback I am aware of. If $U$ is any subset of $V_2$, then its pullback $f^{-1}(U)$ is perfectly defined by $f^{-1}(U)=\{x\in V_1 | f(x)\in U\}$. For the function $f(x)=x^2$ with $V_1=V_2=\mathbb R$, the set $U=(-1,0)$ is not pulled back to *anything*, but to the empty set, which is something very clear and precise (the set that contains nothing).

Comment: @sequence: really? did you show your professor this exact proof? Without changing a single word? In that case, I would suggest you strongly to invite your professor to this website...

Comment: My bad, I messed up the statement. I've now reformulated the statement. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 0):

The proof is not okay..

In order to show that $f^{-1}(U)$ is closed start with a limit point say $x$ of $f^{-1}(U)$.

We can find a sequence $x_n\in f^{-1}(U)$ such that $x_n\to x$.

Now $x_n\in f^{-1}(U)\implies f(x_n)\in U$. As $f$ is continuous $x_n\to x\implies f(x_n)\to f(x)$

As $U$ is closed so it contains all its limit points hence $f(x_n)\in U;f(x_n)\to f(x)\implies f(x)\in U\implies x\in  f^{-1}(U)$

Comment: Can you please point out what exactly is not OK in the proof?

Comment: As pointed out in the beginning "in order... " you should start with a limit point in $ f^{-1}(U)$ not in $U$@sequence

Comment: Why should it necessarily start with a limit point of $f^{-1}(U)$ and not $U$? I don't see a problem with that, as long as the proof is logically correct.

Comment: Because u want to show that $f^{-1}(U)$ is closed

Comment: But that's what I showed at the end of the proof after applying $f^{-1}$ to an equality. I showed that $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} x_n=x$ for all $x$ and that $x\in f^{-1}(U)$.